# How to find solutions of PDEs or explain they don't exist

Tags: partial-differential-equations, examples-counterexamples

Consider the equation $u_x + 3x^2y^2u_y = 0$ :
Find a solution satisfying $u(x, 0) = 1/(1+x)$, or explain why no such solution exists.

My attempt:
I've managed to solve the equation and find the general solution as $u(x,y)=f(x^3 + 1/y)$.
Now I know $u(x,0) = f(x^3)$, but I'm not sure what method to use further to show that solutions exist or don't exist.

Comment: There are two errors in your Post : ((1)) It should be $+1/y$ , not $-1/y$ , which I have corrected , thinking that it might be typo. ((2)) Here that $f(x^3)$ is not right. It is more Deeper Issue & It is the crux of the question here , hence I will explain it in my Answer Post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we know that $u(x,y)$ is in terms of $f(z)$ , where $z=x^3+1/y$ , we already know that $z$ is not defined at $y=0$ (due to $1/0$) , hence $f$ is not defined there & eventually $u$ is not defined there.
In other words , there is no Solution where $y=0$ occurs.
[[ Check that $u(x,0)=f(x^3+1/0) \not = f(x^3)$ ]]

In Case the Criteria given had been $u(x,1)=1/(1+x)$ , we can get Solutions like $u(x,y)=(1+\sqrt[3]{(x^3+1/y-1)})^{-1}$.
It will become $u(x,1)=(1+\sqrt[3]{(x^3+1/1-1)})^{-1}=1/(1+x)$.

In Case the PDE Solution had been $u(x,y)=f(x^3+y)$ , we can make it $u(x,0)=f(x^3+0)=f(x^3)$ to get Solutions.

Unfortunately , what we have here involves $1/0$ , hence there are no Solutions.

Comment: What if I was given something like $u(0,y) = 1/(1+y)$? Then I would have $u(0,y) = 1/y$ right? Does it have a solution then?

Comment: Yes , that will have a Solution **except** at $y=-1$ & $y=0$ & where-ever the Denominator becomes $0$ [[ I think your comment has typos ]]

Comment: Could you give me a rough idea of how we would find the solution with those conditions? Would it be $u(x,y) = (1+\sqrt[3]{(x^3+1/y-1)})^{-1}$, 
$u(0,y) = (1+\sqrt[3]{(1/y-1)})^{-1}$

Comment: That is a totally new Question , the Current Question has been clarified here , showing that there is no Solution involving $1/0$ & the Comment Box is too small to answer new Questions. It is not clear which Conditions you are now referring to , though the Solutions look right !